# Numpy records in the c api

Tags: python, numpy

I'm playing with writing some C code to speed up an inner loop in my
python code. This loop operates on a numpy record, e.g. soemthing like
this:

```
a = numpy.zeros((10,), dtype=[("myfvalue" ,"float"), ("myc", "int8"),
                              ("anotheri", "uint64")])
```

which is then passed into c code like so:

```
myCFunc(a, "blah")
```

I was wondering if someone had an example of how to access particular
columns of "a" in the C func. Clearly, this is going to involve  a
`PyArray_Descr.fields` somewhere, but an example would really help make
things clearer for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of examples on the Scipy Wiki:

- [C Extensions to NumPy and Python](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/C_Extensions/NumPy_arrays)